# Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH!

Tags: homebrew

I can't see my NTFS hard drive in finder sidebar. I have to open it from Disk Utility.

And brew doctor show this warning:

> Homebrew's sbin was not found in your PATH but you have installed formulae that put executables in /usr/local/sbin. Consider setting the PATH for example like so echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

I am all new with these stuff just want to use my old hard drive on my new Mac.

Could you please tell me how to fix this ?

Comment: Though I can imagine how your NTFS drive is related to brew this question is missing an explicit link between NTFS and brew doctor. Flagged unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @klanomath The user [deleted the first time they tried to ask this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228752/homebrews-sbin-was-not-found-in-your-path). It's not even clear the warning is relevant without knowing what package is being brewed and whether it needs further installation steps or not.

Answer (score 5):

The error message itself is telling you what to do. Open Terminal and run the command specified, by pasting this in and pressing Enter:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```